# Heroku Install Troubleshooting on Mac OS 10.6.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This MBP is brand new. I installed Rails, and it went swimmingly. Now Heroku is giving me this error on install:

MacBook-Pro:~ caselas$ sudo gem install heroku
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing heroku:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Here is this, to help diagnos:

MacBook-Pro:~ caselas$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/caselas/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

have you installed Xcode and the 'Unix Development' option during the install?

John.